# Java Logger not rotating log files

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, rhel7

I'm using Tomcat 8.0.21 on RHEL 7. In my Java code I'm logging to a text file with `java.util.logging.Logger`.

There is always only one log file. If I restart Tomcat the logging starts again from that moment and all previous logs are gone.

I added `%g` to file name as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704863/java-logger-create-file-with-rotation-number-log-as-suffix) but it only adds 0 to file name and no rotation occurs.

Here is my code to create the `FileHandler`. `strFilePath` value is for example "/tmp/mylog.log". `LogFormatter` is my own class.

```
// Need to set format with own formatter class to get plain text to one line (default format is XML).
FileHandler file_handler = new FileHandler(strFilePath);
file_handler.setFormatter(new LogFormatter());
logger.addHandler(file_handler);
```

On my Windows 7 laptop logs rotate fine using the same code and Tomcat version.

How can I enable Java `Logger` log file rotation on my RHEL server?

**Edit:** I guess I could just add timestamp to file name when constructing `FileHandler`. I'm going to try that.

Comment: Seriously? Use SLF4J with Logback. This is eons better than JUL.

Comment: Have you read [Tomact FAQs](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q9)?

Comment: I'm not talking about Tomcat logging but logging from my own Java code. In my understanding the FAQ talks about Tomcat's own logging. I'll clarify my question a bit.

Comment: Can you include some of your code you are using to setup the FileHandler?

Comment: Added a little bit of code and an idea of adding time stamp to file name. Let me know if you want to see more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileHandler only rotates when the limit is exceeded (or unable to lock the file).  If you want to rotate files by time then you have to code for that. If you want to just trigger a rotation then just create a throw away file handler with a limit of zero bytes before you open your actual file handler.

```
new FileHandler(pattern, 0, 1, false).close();
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have added a limit.

Comment: Missing limit must have been the reason although I'm not sure why I got at least some kind of rotation on my Windows PC. Anyway I think for now I'll stick to my code which adds timestamp to file name for clarity. If file size starts to get too big I'll add limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution but I think I won't lose old logs when I construct the `FileHandler` this way:

```
FileHandler file_handler = new FileHandler(strFilePath.replace("<timestamp>", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss").format(new Date())));
```

I have "`<timestamp>`" string in the file name and that gets replaced here. I think a new log file is only created when I restart Tomcat so the log files might get big. But this is the best I've come up so far.